# Is there anyway to set selection column as the second column after expand icon in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am learning Ant Design, and I wonder how to design the table with expand icon as the first column and checkbox column as the second one, like this [this](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-dynamic-settings)

I see  regular Table element has a default first column with a checkbox. I don't want to use the `state` variable as in the code example provided [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oc4ub).

I don't know how to set the columns as I want.

Thanks for all support.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to create a Table like [this](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-dynamic-settings) example but regular Table element has a default first column with a checkbox, is it correct? Antd provided a code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oc4ub) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.